# RF script automation

Tags: radio

First time poster, so forgive me if I missed anything.

I'm trying to get an automation script working with some RF modules.
I want a script to wait for a certain code, and then output 1/0 to a file.

I can do this with one channel:

```
until /home/pi/433Utils/RPi_utils/RFSniffer | grep "Received 1115473" ; echo 1 > /home/pi/A ; do sleep 1 ; done
```

But I want this for all channels (A/B/C/D/E).
How do I go about doing this?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Although for sure what you want to achieve can be done with a bash script, I would nevertheless suggest that you take a look at the [c-implementation of the program RFSniffer](https://github.com/ninjablocks/433Utils/blob/master/RPi_utils/RFSniffer.cpp) you are presumably using.

Basically the program uses [the rcswitch library](https://github.com/sui77/rc-switch), creates a RCSwitch object and calls the methods `RCSwitch.available()` and `RCSwitch.getReceivedValue()`.

Similar to `RFSniffer`, a possible solution consists in calling both methods in an endless while loop. The integer value you get in `RCSwitch.getReceivedValue()` you then need to compare with the respective values you expect for your channels A to E. If you detect one of them, you simply write to the respective file as in your bash script solution.